# Uploading file to server with Java and PHP

Tags: java, php

I'm making a Java application, and need the user to be able to upload a file to a server through PHP. The problem is that when the user uploads the file, the PHP script doesn't seem to "catch" the file.

This is the code I have so far.

PHP:

```
<?php
    
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "1";
    exit();
}
echo "0";

?>
```

Java:

```
String filename = "C:\Users\XXX\Pictures\Capture.PNG";

public void uploadFile() {
            text = "";
            String CrLf = "\r\n";
            String filename = filepath.split("/")[filepath.split("/").length-1];
            
            URLConnection conn = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            
        try {
            URL con = new URL(connection);
            conn = con.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
                        
            InputStream imgIS = new FileInputStream(filepath);
                        byte[] imgData = new byte[imgIS.available()];
                        imgIS.read(imgData);

            String message1 = "";
                        message1 += "-----------------------------4664151417711" + CrLf;
                        message1 += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"Image0001.png\""
                            + CrLf;
                        message1 += "Content-Type: image/png" + CrLf;
                        message1 += CrLf;

                        // the image is sent between the messages in the multipart message.

                        String message2 = "";
                        message2 += CrLf + "-----------------------------4664151417711--"
                            + CrLf;

                        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------4664151417711");
                        // might not need to specify the content-length when sending chunked
                        // data.
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf((message1
                            .length() + message2.length() + imgData.length)));

                        System.out.println("open os");
                        os = conn.getOutputStream();

                        System.out.println(message1);
                        os.write(message1.getBytes());

                        // SEND THE IMAGE
                        int index = 0;
                        int size = 1024;
                        do {
                            System.out.println("write:" + index);
                            if ((index + size) > imgData.length) {
                                size = imgData.length - index;
                            }
                            os.write(imgData, index, size);
                            index += size;
                        } while (index < imgData.length);
                        System.out.println("written:" + index);

                        System.out.println(message2);
                        os.write(message2.getBytes());
                        os.flush();

                        System.out.println("open is");
                        is = conn.getInputStream();

                        char buff = 512;
                        int len;
                        byte[] data = new byte[buff];
                        do {
                            System.out.println("READ");
                            len = is.read(data);

                            if (len > 0) {
                               System.out.println(new String(data, 0, len));
                         }
                        } while (len > 0);

                        System.out.println("DONE");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        System.out.println("Close connection");
                        try {
                            os.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        try {

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
        }
```

When getting the output from the PHP script, it always returns a "0".
I've tried a lot of different things, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Use an absolute path, and ensure permissions are correct on the destination folder.

Comment: @miken32 I've already tried the direct path thing, and I've also checked all permissions

Comment: How you will select file on real case with html input or by direct path as you mentioned above?